# Matlab plot 3d graph

Tags: matlab

i created an 3d Mat, some of the points in the Mat are from calculation and some points in the mat are invalid for me and therefore i put "inf" in those points

however when i write a code to plot this 3D graph:

```
rotating_vec=logspace(0,log10(8e3-1),50);
adding_vec=logspace(0,log10(8e3-1),50);
```

and the code for ploting the 3D graph:

```
surf(adding_vec,rotating_vec,3d_mat_to_plot);
```

the matlab show me an error message (male_spc_3d_mat is a 51X51 mat, which i get it from a function that i created):

```
rotate_vec=logspace(500,log10(8e3-1),50);
rotate_vec=[25,rotate_vec];
add_vec=rotate_vec;
>> [rotate_mat_mesh,add_mat_mesh]=meshgrid(rotate_vec,add_vec);
>> surf(rotate_mat_mesh,add_mat_mesh,male_spc_3d_mat)
Warning: Axes limits too large.  Not rendering... 
Warning: Axis limits outside float precision, use ZBuffer or
Painters instead. Not rendering 
Warning: Axis limits outside float precision, use ZBuffer or
Painters instead. Not rendering
```

what is the problem? and how can i fix it?

thanks alot

Comment: Well if you have manually changed points to `inf` are you really surprised that matlab cannot plot them?

Comment: i didnt changed it manually, my function that create the male_spc_3d_mat, put in the indexes which i didnt want to plot them :"inf"...i tried to do a vec with inf points and the plot(x,vec) works for me and didnt plot the "inf" points, so i think that it sould be the same with the "surf" function

Comment: Try setting your invalid points to `NaN`, not to `inf`.

Comment: hi, its still the same problem...no one knows the solution for this?

Comment: have you tried changing the X,Y grid? does `surf(male_spc_3d_mat);` gives reasonable plot?